# Raspberry pi with two USB 2.5 inch Hard drives and powering them in parallel via one 5V PSU

Tags: power, raspberry-pi, parallel, hard-drive

I'm a hobbyist/tinkerer and want to make sure I don't fry my equipment by doing it wrong.

I'm trying to connect two/three 2.5 in USB HDD's to a Raspberry Pi 3. The power supply I have is 5V 2.5A and I plan to upgrade that to a 5V 4A or 5A whichever is available/needed. (At startup each drive can take between 600 to 1100 mA and then falls back down to 400 mA during normal operation.)

I imagine that just by providing higher PSU to Pi will not suffice and I should look into separating the Data and power of my HDD's so that the Data is still connecting to Pi, but the power is provided by the PSU directly.

To oversimplify - I'm thinking of taking the 5V 4A PSU and using a Y connector splitting it into two. 
1. goes to Power the Pi.
2. goes to power the HDDs.

My question is:
- Is this the correct way to do it ?
- What kind of circuitry do I need to build so I can power these reliably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how much current is taken by the HDDs?

Comment: My understanding is that at startup each drive can take between 600 to 1100 mA and then falls back down to 400 mA during normal operation.

Comment: RPI is not designed to power high current devices as a host, all the USB ports run off the main 5V rail on the RPI, regardless if you are using usb or a dc jack to power the device, both of these inputs are actually upstream of a 1A smd fuse so powering two devices at 400mA each will leave only 200ma for the RPI, all the low voltage regulators, pio,etc.... The best case is to inject power to the usb externally using a dedicated power board, functionally this is identical to a powered hub, but it can be done in the same box if you really need it to.

Comment: A regular USB Hub (powered from a wall adapter) can supply all four USB ports with proper power to run all USB-compliant devices. The RPI has the same power topology - four downstream ports. Why hubs can be designed to supply enough power, but RPI can't?

Comment: Thanks Crasic. Thats essentially the direction I want to go. I am seeking clarification on how best to approach this. I.e. What all components do I need on that power board? 5 v input from psu, going out to two usb drives, any capacitors, diodes or such needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To oversimplify - I'm thinking of taking the 5V 4A PSU and using a Y connector splitting it into two. 1. goes to Power the Pi. 2. goes to power the HDDs.

You could do that and it would work. However, you would bypass the fuse between the Pi's USB-B jack and its 5V power rail. So if a component fails in short-circuit mode, it can draw the whole 4A (through the 5V line of the HDD's USB cable) and potentially start a fire.

You can eliminate that risk by cutting the 5V line in the USB cables leading from the Pi to the HDDs. However, do not cut the GND line, otherwise your HDDs won't have a clean ground reference (only indirectly through the PSU) and communication will likely fail.

So to summarize:

- Connect 5V and GND from PSU to Pi.
- Connect 5V and GND from PSU to HDDs.
- Connect D+, D- and GND from Pi to HDDs, **but not** 5V.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the confirmation I needed. I also appreciate the warning on keeping the GND line. I ended up reusing my Pi for another purpose, I still intend to do this project. It'll be some time before I get to try this.
P.S. I tried +1 but it says I don't have enough rating to upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi (all variants) are not well-engineered for correct power delivery on USB ports. Your best bet is to use a good quality self-powered (via a wall adapter) hub, preferably USB-IF certified, and USB 3.0 type (for higher supply capability).

Comment: Thanks Ali. I should have included, my preference is not to use a powered hub. I'd like this to have the smallest footprint possible and be contained inside one box.

Comment: I have a suggestion how to solve the problem, but I already got -2 for this, see http://superuser.com/questions/1123083/external-hdd-3-0-for-a-raspberry-pi-3/1123119#1123119

Comment: You will likely need to add a power DC jack to bypass their weak micro-B receptacle.

Comment: Thanks Ali. Looking at your suggestion in other post, it seems as though you're suggesting to provide power to the existing USB port of Raspberry pi. That may be the reason why you got -2.  I am thinking of bypassing the internal circuitry of Raspberry Pi so I can provide power to HDD directly. I don't know if it is as simple as running a wire across to another board or do I need any resistors/capacitors/diodes along the way so there is no back flow.

Comment: If your drives are bus-powered, then how do you plan to break their USB cables, to inject more into VBUS? Using Y-cables will essentially add the same extra wire between power adapter and USB port on Pi3. The wire I propose does not run to "another board", it is just beefing up the power pass from Pi3 input power to USB ports, bypassing whatever they have on-board, all on the same Pi3 board. Pi3 Foundation refuses to disclose their schematics around USB connectors, so I can't provide any details how this will affect their possible "overcurrent protection".

Comment: My thoughts are essentially an home made Y cable which will have four pins connecting to HDD, the two Data pins will connect to the pi USB port (and ignoring the power pins on pi) , the other two power pins from Y cable will connect to a small board where I provide the bypass from PSU. I'm thinking this should be safer method as the Pi USB does not come in contact with the external current. But I do not know if there are any other safe guards I need to put in place to ensure that the Volt and current remain constant for the Pi and the HDDs.

Comment: Note, though USB is symetrical, you can't power a USB device completely independent from the Pi's supply, because for detecting the device, there's a resistor from D+/D- to Vdd inside it. So you have to use the same power supply for both, or connect at least GND between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be modifying the raspberry pi. soldering new wires for +5 and 0V to the underside of the USB sockets and then connecting those wires to a 5V power supply.

you loose the protection given by the polyfuse so a fault on the GPIO header could burn up tracks on the raspberry pi, a fault on the USB is most likely to cause the power supply to shut down (so long as it's a reasonable size, and not a 20A monster).

this power supply would run the USB peripherals and the raspberry pi itself.